# Does Super User use some kind of automatic algorithm to close threads?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, moderators

I am surprised [Which wiki package does this site use?](https://superuser.com/questions/124798/which-wiki-package-does-this-site-use-closed) was closed.

If it isn't software-related then I don't know what it is. It isn't programming related, it isn't server related, it isn't web design or development related so what should it be?

Comment: It's not like every question in life must belong on one of the trilogy sites? (As an aside: the one-and-only real Super User web site likes the space in its name.)

Comment: If you're still interested in the answer repost the question on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 18):

Super User recently [swapped out one processor for two](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/moderator-changes-on-super-user/) to better the performance of the hyper-threaded closing algorithm used on the site.

According to [the SU FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq), that particular question is off-topic as it deals [purely with a website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy).

It doesn't belong anywhere on the current trilogy make-up of sites.

Comment: The previous processor was overclocked for so long, I don't know how it held all that time.

Answer (score 5):

Super User is *not* about websites, it is about computer software. If the question had have been "How do I use this wiki on my PC?", it would probably have been closed as a duplicate, but been an entirely valid question.