# Can the Community user's avatar stay a unicorn?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, gravatar, community-user, unicorns

For some reason... I don't know why... but it just works for a background process.

Would be a fitting reminder of today, ongoing. A tribute, as it were.

Comment: you think the moderators are background processes??  (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44322/does-super-user-uses-some-kind-of-automatic-algo-to-close-threads/44323#44323 notwithstanding)

Comment: Are you talking about the Community account?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community  If that is what you are thinking about, I kinda like the idea.

Comment: You might consider @random a background process ;-)

Comment: ah.  no, "Moderator ♦" isn't the user's name; that phrase appears on the profile pages of *all* mods (check the list at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about).  that user's name is **"Community"**.

Comment: Mea culpa! 15chars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send email to him (Community User) at team at stackoverflow.com , and ask him directly to change his gravatar to Unicornify.

I've checked his email hash, thats his email.

```
>>> hashlib.md5("team@stackoverflow.com").hexdigest()
'a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e'
```

You may check his email hash at his profile source - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1

Comment: Good idea, done.

Comment: how you get the e-mail from hash?

Comment: @user1135588 You can't. YOU guessed the email address (it's in the page footer), and only used the hash to verify it.