# Who can see the e-mail address that I entered in my user info?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make e-mail invisible on Stack Exchange profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77453/how-to-make-e-mail-invisible-on-stack-exchange-profile)

When I enter an e-mail address in my user info, where will it show up? Will other people be able to see it or is it used only for notifications?

Comment: yourself, and moderators

Comment: And the few who think they can [decipher the avatar hash](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk/79856#79856), @YOU.

Comment: @Arjan, also like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44941/can-the-community-users-avatar-stay-a-unicorn/44962#44962)? :D

Comment: @Arjan: That's not `deciphering`...that's guessing and hashing. There's a big difference.

Comment: I know, @Bobby. Hence the "who think". But true, a smiley, or linking the "who think" rather than the "decipher" would have been better!

Comment: @Arjan: Ah, I see. Sorry, my irony detector must still be in repair. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What, you mean this email address?

## GRIMMIG@GMAIL.COM

Nobody except you and community moderators.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should go to google and reserve that email right now. ;-)

Comment: @grim but seriously see our privacy policy http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy etc

Comment: What email address?

Comment: @grimmig, I think you already [late](http://www.google.co.jp/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22GRIMMIG%40gmail.com%22)

Comment: I **can** see that email address, since I am not **you** I must be a community moderator  [:-)

Comment: aggressive funniness for the win